# Group a JSON url by userId in React Native

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, react-native

Using this JSON file, https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, and React Native, the page should display posts grouped by UserId as follows:

- User Id : 1

  - post
  - post
- User Id: 2

  - post
  - post
- ...

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checking below link how to do so on **react-native**:

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-groupby

Here is my example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import groupBy from 'json-groupby';

const data = [...your data array];

class App extends React.Component { 
    render(){
        console.log('original data:', data);
        var after = groupBy(data, ['userId']);
        console.log('after groupby:', after);

        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Hello World!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

> Result after groupBy:

[image]

> For more detail pls read the document.
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-groupby